# Pull a message off a queue that wasn't put on the queue by Laravel?

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-sqs

I have a Symfony application putting messages on a queue. 
Im wondering if Laravel is capable of pulling messages off of a queue that come from a different application? (i.e. not Laravel formatted)

I know Laravel is capable of pulling messages off of a queue that it's workers place onto the queue in a Laravel format.

Just wondering if possible to use a Laravel worker to read a queue message placed onto the queue from a different app.

Comment: By *queue* what exactly is it? For example: Laravel supports many queue drivers such as database, Redis, Amazon SQS and Beanstalkd. It is no doubt possible to do what you're asking but to be able to give you an idea on how to do it, we'd need to know what the Symfony application is using as a queue

Comment: OH thanks for the guidance! Basically if say another application puts a json message on a queue can a laravel worker pull that off and process it? Or is it required to be in a certain format that the Laravel worker creates.